# apidescription does not contain a definition for 'responsedescription'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I get the error apidescription does not contain a definition for 'responsedescription'" on using :

**Type type=api.ResponseDescription.ResponseType ?? api.ResponseDescription.DeclaredType;**
where api is of type System.Web.Http.Description.ApiDescription.

I have included the reference to System.Net.HTTP.
Any help would be appreciated.